# Encoding of measurements exported from photoshop CS4 to read in Python

Tags: python, encoding, photoshop, cs4

I exported some measurements (not image files) from Photoshop in CS4. [This page](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/measurement.html) describes the tool in CS6 and up, where the measurements nicely export to a csv with utf-8 encoding. In CS4, it exports as a tab-delimited text, and I can't figure out what the encoding is.

Now I want to read the file in Python using pandas or csv. I've tried `utf8`, `ISO-8859-1`, `US-ASCII`, `cp1252`, and `latin1` encoding, all of which give me errors (i.e. `invalid start byte`, `NULL byte`, and `EOF inside string`).

How can I read this file?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting close to posting one of these files here to see if someone could figure it out, but before doing so I opened one in Excel. When I did Save As, Excel defaulted to a utf-16 text file.

I was able to open these files with csv and `encoding = utf-16`, and with pandas `read_table` and `encoding = utf-16, engine = 'python'`. `read_csv` didn't work.

Seems rather obscure to me, so I'm posting in case this helps someone else.